# Calling web service from SSIS

Tags: web-services, web, ssis

i am trying to call a web service from a SSIS package, getting the below error

Code: 0xC002F304    Description: An error occurred with the following error message: "Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.WebServiceTask.WebserviceTaskException: Could not read the Web Services Description Language (WSDL) file. The input WSDL file is not valid. The following error occurred while reading the file. There is an error in XML document (0, 0)..     at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.WebServiceTask.WebServiceTaskUtil..ctor(Object connection, String downloadedWSDL)     at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.WebServiceTask.WebServiceTask.executeThr

can some one pls help

when i deploy in to production server, is it necessary for me to ship the WSDL file along with the package or, does it get downloaded automotically